# If $\theta : H \rightarrow G/H$ why is $\theta(x) = g_xH$ used in this proof? - G -sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

I don't understand why the function in the red box of the picture maps $x \rightarrow g_xH$ when it's previously defined as a function from $H \rightarrow G//H$ which since $H=G_{x_0}$ wouldn't the map have to be $g \rightarrow gH$ where $gx_0 = x_0$?  Why does the function argument have a different domain than its definition?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's just the result of a typo: it should have been $\theta: \mathbf{X} \rightarrow G/H$.

After all, the intention was to prove that $X$ and $G/H$ are isomorphic, and $\theta$ is a candidate for the function that shows this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove that the map $\theta:X\longrightarrow G\,{//}\,H$ is a well defined bijection. It is well defined since if $x_1=x_2\in X$ then because the transitivity there are elements $g_1$ and $g_2$ in $G$ such that $g_1 x_0 = x_1$ and $g_2 x_0 = x_2$. So $g_1 x_0 = g_2 x_0$ then $g_1 g_{2}^{-1}\in G_{x_0}=H$. This means $\theta(x_1)=g_1 H = g_2 H=\theta(x_2)$. So $\theta$ is well defined. For the inverse you can define a map $\theta^{-1}(gH):=gx_{0}$. In the proof you cite above they show that $\theta(gx)=g\theta(x)$ this implies that $\theta(gx_0)=gH$ so $\theta$ is a bijective map since $\theta(x_0)=g_{x_0}H=H$.